# Project wide diagnostics in Deno?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I'm trying to get errors from all files in a project, not only open files.

Is there a Deno version of this setting:

```json
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
```

A command to scan entire project for errors from terminal would also work.

I'm using VSCode and Deno 1.28.2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Type Checking](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.2/advanced/typescript/overview#type-checking) section of the manual page “Overview of TypeScript in Deno”.

> You can type-check your code (without executing it) using the following command:
>
> ```txt
> deno check module.ts
> ```

This will type-check all local modules involved in the module graph: all imports of that module — and imports of imports, etc. — on your file system, and emit compiler diagnostics for any problems.