# oak on Deno - How do I build a URL to a route?

Tags: deno, oak

I come from a land of ASP.NET Core. Having fun learning a completely new stack.

I'm used to being able to:

1. name a route "orders"
2. give it a path like `/customer-orders/{id}`
3. register it
4. use the routing system to build a URL for my named route

An example of (4) might be to pass a `routeName` and then `routeValues` which is an object like `{ id = 193, x = "y" }` and the routing system can figure out the URL `/customer-orders/193?x=y` - notice how it just appends extraneous key-vals as params.

Can I do something like this in oak on Deno?? Thanks.

Update: I am looking into some functions on the underlying regexp tool the routing system uses. It doesn't seem right that this often used feature should be so hard/undiscoverable/inaccessible.

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#compile-reverse-path-to-regexp

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0), including the Router section (linked)? If so, what was confusing?

Comment: Hey Jesse(?) I am the odd guy that reads the docs fully before writing any code! I sometimes make notes in public https://github.com/lukepuplett/notes though I didn't for oak. Anyway, there's everything about routes and matching a URL but not building a URL - unless I'm blind. I will read it all again.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635313/oak-on-deno-how-do-i-build-a-url-to-a-route?noredirect=1#comment131748001_74635313) No worries. I asked because — while it's not unfair to point out that SO is full of [answers that are essentially rehashed info from documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74635291/438273), that's not exactly the purpose of the site, and — if you can better pinpoint what it is that's not covered by the examples in the docs, you will probably get a better answer. TS/JS isn't ASP.NET and concepts aren't the same — not everything translates exactly.

Comment: It might be that I need to use the regexp lib, but I'm confused because making a URL to print into an <a href> from a route in your app is a basic usecase, but I can't find it documented and it doesn't Google. Even GPT-3 doesn't know and that's basically God ;)

Comment: It seems like you might be asking more than one question. I provided an answer about working with the incoming request URL. If you'd like to learn about building HTML for use in a response, there's already lots of documentation on this site (and elsewhere) covering that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you mean by "building" a URL, but the URL associated to the incoming request is defined by the requesting client, and is available in each middleware callback function's [context](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0#context) parameter at `context.request.url` as an instance of the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class.

The [documentation](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0#router) provides some examples of using a router and the middleware callback functions that are associated to routes in Oak.

Here's an example module which demonstrates accessing the URL-related data in a request:

`so-74635313.ts`:

```ts
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";

const router = new Router({ prefix: "/customer-orders" });

router.get("/:id", async (ctx, next) => {
  // An instance of the URL class:
  const { url } = ctx.request;

  // An instance of the URLSearchParams class:
  const { searchParams } = url;

  // A string:
  const { id } = ctx.params;

  const serializableObject = {
    id,
    // Iterate all the [key, value] entries and collect into an array:
    searchParams: [...searchParams.entries()],
    // A string representation of the full request URL:
    url: url.href,
  };

  // Respond with the object as JSON data:
  ctx.response.body = serializableObject;
  ctx.response.type = "application/json";

  // Log the object to the console:
  console.log(serializableObject);

  await next();
});

const app = new Application();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

function printStartupMessage({ hostname, port, secure }: {
  hostname: string;
  port: number;
  secure?: boolean;
}): void {
  if (!hostname || hostname === "0.0.0.0") hostname = "localhost";
  const address =
    new URL(`http${secure ? "s" : ""}://${hostname}:${port}/`).href;
  console.log(`Listening at ${address}`);
  console.log("Use ctrl+c to stop");
}

app.addEventListener("listen", printStartupMessage);

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

In a terminal shell (I'll call it shell A), the program is started:

```txt
% deno run --allow-net so-74635313.ts
Listening at http://localhost:8000/
Use ctrl+c to stop
```

Then, in another shell (I'll call it shell B), a network request is sent to the server at the route described in your question — and the response body ([JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) text) is printed below the command:

```txt
% curl 'http://localhost:8000/customer-orders/193?x=y'
{"id":"193","searchParams":[["x","y"]],"url":"http://localhost:8000/customer-orders/193?x=y"}
```

Back in shell A, the output of the `console.log` statement can be seen:

```txt
{
  id: "193",
  searchParams: [ [ "x", "y" ] ],
  url: "http://localhost:8000/customer-orders/193?x=y"
}
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is used to send an interrupt signal (`SIGINT`) to the deno process and stop the server.

Comment: If this didn't address the question completely, then hopefully it provides you with enough context to understand the difference between how I interpreted your question and what you intended to communicate/ask. Perhaps your question was more about using the built-in `URL` class (linked in the question)? If so, then MDN will document how to work with that class. At any rate: let me know if there's a dimension to the question that I didn't cover in the answer.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your time today with trying to help me. It's really appreciated, and I apologise for not making clear what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am fortunately working with a React developer today!

Between us, we've found the `.url(routeName, ...)` method on the `Router` instance and that does exactly what I need!

Here's the help for it:

```
  /** Generate a URL pathname for a named route, interpolating the optional
   * params provided.  Also accepts an optional set of options. */
```

Here's it in use in context:

```
export const routes = new Router()
  .get(
    "get-test",
    "/test",
    handleGetTest,
  );

function handleGetTest(context: Context) {
  console.log(`The URL for the test route is: ${routes.url("get-test")}`);
}

// The URL for the test route is: /test
```